# Programmers.SE Contest: The Complete Outline

Tags: discussion, contest

### Wait! Programmers.SE is having a contest!?

*What have you been living under a rock?*

Just kidding (maybe). Yes, Programmers is having a contest. And it's going to be awesome!

### So how will this contest work?

The contest will be divided into 4 weeks. For each of the 4 weeks, there will be a tag dedicated to it. The schedule will go like this:

1. [data-structures](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structures) -- May 7 ([results](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3591/25936))
2. [documentation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation) -- May 14 ([results](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3604/25936))
3. [history](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) -- May 21 ([results](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3631/25936))
4. [algorithms](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) -- May 28 ([results](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652/25936))

Each week, users who post questions and answers for that weeks tag will have their post entered into the contest. The following categories can win:

- **Best Answer:** The best answer from the week will be a winner. Best answer is judged by **votes**. Any answer to a closed question is ineligible.
- **Best Question:** The best question from the week will also be awarded. Best question is not judged on votes, but instead **views**. Closed questions will be disqualified. ***We encourage advertising your question (on non-SE sites) to get more views. Please do not spam the chat rooms.***

Remember, you are only eligible if you post under the current week's tag.

### Prizes!

Best of all, we try to get you the best prizes possible. In order to do that, we had to put on a few restrictions. But **winners can choose their own site-related prize from Amazon, as long as it:**

- Is under $50 (including shipping and handling)
- Is related to the site and its topic

If your one prize does not use up the $50, you may choose up to 3 different things (still has to be under $50 all total).

### So when do we start?

The contest is going on now!

### Important Notes of Eligibility and Such

- You must have a valid email address in your profile so that we can contact you and ask you what you want from Amazon (if you win).
- No closed questions or negatively scored questions (regardless of views).
- SE employees are ineligible.
- The question you are asking or answering must contain the contest tag to be eligible
- Bounties on contest questions are more than welcome.

Comment: I've purged all the comments, as they were getting a bit off topic and the different discussions were concluded. We will do an evaluation of the contest after the contest ends. If you would like to discuss the contest now, feel free to do so in the [contest chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2050/programmer-contest-conspiracy-room).

Comment: @YannisRizos I posted results for week 4, but forgot how to find user flair...

Answer (score 9):

### Results for Week 1 [data-structures]

- [How should I build the data structure for a dynamic, unlimited-size "maze"?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148250/how-should-i-build-the-data-structure-for-a-dynamic-unlimited-size-maze)

  Views: 795, Top voted answer: [Bubblewrap](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148251/25936) (31)
- [Programming language with pattern matching in trees](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148045/programming-language-with-pattern-matching-in-trees)

  Views: 163, Top voted answer: [SK-logic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148061/25936) (4)
- [Data structure for file search](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147988/data-structure-for-file-search)

  Views: 99, Top voted answer: [Izkata](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/147995/25936) (10)
- [When programmers talk about "data structures", what are they referring to?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147886/when-programmers-talk-about-data-structures-what-are-they-referring-to)

  Views: 590, Top voted answer: [Alex](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/147887/25936) (15)
- [Are trees organised by a "firstchild, nextsibling" structure? If not, why not?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147708/are-trees-organised-by-a-firstchild-nextsibling-structure-if-not-why-not)

  Views: 300, Top voted answer: [arnaud](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/147714/25936) (6)
- [Is there a way to track data structure dependencies from the database, through the tiers, all the way out to a web page?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147678/is-there-a-way-to-track-data-structure-dependencies-from-the-database-through-t)

  Views: 178, Top voted answers: [Pratik](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/147731/25936) (2) & [Old Pro](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148290/25936) (2)
- [What is the Bible of Hashing?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147668/what-is-the-bible-of-hashing)

  Views: 271, Top voted answers: [Chris](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/147680/25936) (1) & [Randall Cook](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/147711/25936) (1)
- [Where would I typically use a Deque in production software?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147667/where-would-i-typically-use-a-deque-in-production-software)

  Views: 252, Top voted answer: [jmq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/147747/25936) (6)
- [What is the most space efficient way to implement a graph data structure?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148313/what-is-the-most-space-efficient-way-to-implement-a-graph-data-structure)

  Views: 147, Top voted answer: [mikera](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148316/25936) (4)
- [What is the difference between an Array and a Stack?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147645/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-a-stack)

  Views: 600, Top voted answer: [Mason Wheeler](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/147647/25936) (32)
- [What is an Aguri tree?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147627/what-is-an-aguri-tree)

  Views: 370, Top voted answer: [World Engineer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/147632/25936) (12)
- [What is the canonical reference on probabilistic data structures?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147537/what-is-the-canonical-reference-on-probabilistic-data-structures)

  Views: 184, Top voted answer: [Dynamic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/147654/25936) (3)

### Question with the most views

[How should I build the data structure for a dynamic, unlimited-size "maze"?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148250/how-should-i-build-the-data-structure-for-a-dynamic-unlimited-size-maze)

[image: profile for Rachel at Programmers, Q&A for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development]

### Top voted answer

[What is the difference between an Array and a Stack?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147645/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-a-stack/147647#147647)

[image: profile for Mason Wheeler at Programmers, Q&A for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development]

Comment: I'll be contacting the winners today to get the ball rolling on the prizes. Congrats, Rachel and Mason Wheeler.

Comment: Wow. I didn't actually know about this. I was just trying to give a good answer to a question. :P

Comment: @MasonWheeler Well thanks for that great answer :P

Answer (score 6):

### Results for Week 2 [documentation]

- [What is the connection between literate programming and the semantic web?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148978/what-is-the-connection-between-literate-programming-and-the-semantic-web)

  Views: 303, Top voted answer: [Robert Harvey](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148980/25936) (11)
- [Should I follow an open source project's documentation patterns even if they are bad?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148900/should-i-follow-an-open-source-projects-documentation-patterns-even-if-they-are)

  Views: 175, Top voted answer: [MainMa](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148905/25936) (8)
- [How to use unit tests as a source of information?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148894/how-to-use-unit-tests-as-a-source-of-information)

  Views: 133, Top voted answer: [Mert](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148899/25936) (7)
- [How do you handle / what do you charge for documentation, training, warranty, changes in scope etc…](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148881/how-do-you-handle-what-do-you-charge-for-documentation-training-warranty-ch)

  Views: 80, Top voted answer: [Ryathal](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148893/25936) (3)
- [What exactly comprises 'Documentation'?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148799/what-exactly-comprises-documentation)

  Views: 157, Top voted answer: [Graham Lee](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148828/25936) (3)
- [Alternative to Perl's POD Documentation in Other Languages?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148607/alternative-to-perls-pod-documentation-in-other-languages)

  Views: 72, Top voted answer: [World Engineer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148612/25936) (3)
- [Does MSDN follow documentation conventions for .NET, and if so is it publicly available?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148534/does-msdn-follow-documentation-conventions-for-net-and-if-so-is-it-publicly-av)

  Views: 197, Top voted answer: [SnOrfus](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148583/25936) (4)
- [Documenting a programming language: Reference Manual](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148488/documenting-a-programming-language-reference-manual)

  Views: 324, Top voted answer: [gnat](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148513/25936) (7)
- [How do I document necessarily complex code structures?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148477/how-do-i-document-necessarily-complex-code-structures)

  Views: 126, Top voted answer: [Kirk Broadhurst](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148491/25936) (4)
- [Are comments considered a form of documentation?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148471/are-comments-considered-a-form-of-documentation)

  Views: 562, Top voted answer: [Oleksi](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148473/25936) (19)

### Question with the most views

[Are comments considered a form of documentation?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148471/are-comments-considered-a-form-of-documentation)

[image: profile for Dynamic at Programmers, Q&A for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development]

### Top voted answer

[Are comments considered a form of documentation?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148473/25936)

[image: profile for Oleksi at Programmers, Q&A for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development]

Answer (score 5):

### Results for Week 3 [history]

- [What does Jamie Zawinski's Law mean?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/150254/25936)

  Views: 678, Top voted answer: [Mason Wheeler](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/150264/25936) (17)
- [First dedicated IDE?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/149998/25936)

  Views: 305, Top voted answer: [Alan B](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/150008/25936) (1)
- [Why was ASCII needed?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/149895/25936)

  Views: 259, Top voted answer: [Steve314](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149904/25936) (9)
- [What was the historical impact of Ariane 5's Flight 501?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/149888/25936)

  Views: 290, Top voted answer: [GordonM](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149915/25936) (5)
- [Who was the first software engineer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/149880/25936)

  Views: 392, Top voted answer: [Thomas Owens](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149899/25936) (15)
- [Who was the first programmer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/149827/25936)

  Views: 774, Top voted answer: [Yannis Rizos](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149828/25936) (43)
- [How were Fortran's original control structures insufficient?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/149594/25936)

  Views: 117, Top voted answer: [James Anderson](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149601/25936) (8)
- [Who created the idea(s) of the first loop constructs?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/149465/25936)

  Views: 1958, Top voted answer: [Yannis Rizos](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149484/25936) (60)
- [Was classical BASIC ever used for commercial software development, and if so, how were limitations overcome?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/149457/25936)

  Views: 5487, Top voted answer: [maple_shaft](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149475/25936) (40)
- [Why did the Haskell committee choose monads to represent I/O?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/149420/25936)

  Views: 549, Top voted answer: [rtperson](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149502/25936) (3)

### Question with the most views

[Was classical BASIC ever used for commercial software development, and if so, how were limitations overcome?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/149457/25936)

[profile for user281377 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/25466.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/25466)

### Top voted answer

[Who created the idea(s) of the first loop constructs?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149484/25936)

[image: profile for Yannis Rizos at Programmers, Q&A for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development]

Answer (score 3):

### Results for Week 4 [algorithms]

- [Number crunching algo for learning multithreading?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151396/number-crunching-algo-for-learning-multithreading)

  Views: 67, Top voted answer: [Rocket Surgeon](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/7071/rocket-surgeon) (3)
- [Given number which equals the sum of some of the 10 numbers. How to determine that given number contains one of 10 numbers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151308/given-number-which-equals-the-sum-of-some-of-the-10-numbers-how-to-determine-th)

  Views: 59, Top voted answer: [MainMa](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/6605/mainma) (3)
- [Efficient Bus Loading](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151050/efficient-bus-loading)

  Views: 194, Top voted answer: [philosodad](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/6883/philosodad) (7)
- [How common are generic-case exponential time algorithms in production software?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150939/how-common-are-generic-case-exponential-time-algorithms-in-production-software)

  Views: 2221, Top voted answer: [Raphael](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/55137/raphael) (4)
- [What is the algorithm for expiring items in key-value storage?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150811/what-is-the-algorithm-for-expiring-items-in-key-value-storage)

  Views: 178, Top voted answer: [vartec](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/14510/vartec) (5)
- [Improving grepping over a huge file performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150746/improving-grepping-over-a-huge-file-performance)

  Views: 94, Top voted answer: [Steven Burnap](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/53141/steven-burnap) (4)
- [Strategy/algorithm to divide fair teams based on history](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150732/strategy-algorithm-to-divide-fair-teams-based-on-history)

  Views: 459, Top voted answer: [Steven Burnap](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/53141/steven-burnap) (3)
- [Return random `list` item by its `weight`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150616/return-random-list-item-by-its-weight)

  Views: 417, Top voted answer: [Benjamin Kloster](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/55140/benjamin-kloster) (14)
- [Why is quicksort better than other sorting algorithms in practice?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150615/why-is-quicksort-better-than-other-sorting-algorithms-in-practice)

  Views: 5726, Top voted answer: [Doc Brown](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/9113/doc-brown) (12)

### Question with most views

[Why is quicksort better than other sorting algorithms in practice?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150615/why-is-quicksort-better-than-other-sorting-algorithms-in-practice)

[image: profile for Raphael at Programmers, Q&A for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development]

### Most voted answer

[Return random `list` item by its `weight`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/150618/34364)

[image: profile for Benjamin Kloster at Programmers, Q&A for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development]

Comment: Let me again give full credit for this steamroll win to [Janoma](http://cs.stackexchange.com/users/24/janoma) who posted the [question on cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/3/98). It is the hottest algorithms question on cs.SE to date and has generated markedly different answers than its copy here. We will have to see about the prize; I certainly did not earn it.

Comment: @Raphael If you want to discuss it with a mod, gladly do so. Go ahead and ping somebody in the Contest Conspiracy chat room.