# Second Programmers Contest?

Tags: discussion, contest

The [first Programmers.SE contest](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3546/programmers-se-contest-the-complete-outline) went pretty well last year, considering how short a time span we put it together. It seemed that those who participated in the contest generally liked it and wanted to do it again.

I'm not going to go into much detail here, I'm simply going to ask the question:

**Do we want to do another Programmers.SE contest?**

---

*Note: If there are a positive number of votes on this post on Monday UTC/GMT (8:00 PM EST) then I will make plans to see how we can progress with this. Anybody interested in contributing can comment here or ping me in the The Whiteboard.*

**[Please, tell us what you think in the contest chat room.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2654)**

Comment: looking through [popular tags](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular), some that feel worth considering are: [tag:agile], [tag:database], [tag:programming-practices], [tag:object-oriented], [tag:code-quality], [tag:tdd], [tag:teamwork], [tag:unit-testing], [tag:documentation], [tag:object-oriented-design], [tag:version-control], [tag:issue-tracking]

Comment: @gnat That's if we were to have the same type of contest as last year. If we do, those are worth looking in to.

Comment: i would love to see self answered, "how I/we solved x" question-answers, if you can make it so it meets site guidelines; would be an interesting format

Comment: @tgkprog we can!! just ask the question and self answer!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but I recommend adding more tags,and perhaps levels. You could do something like: best beginner question in so and so.